# Why is inset producing different results on horizontal to vertical faces?

Tags: modeling

For years I've worked with inset to make many shapes and objects, most notably guns and other game asset-type things.
However recently inset has stopped working as I need it to, when using it on vertical faces. On horizontal faces however it works fine. 
Refer to the attached images.
[image: side face selected]
[image: top face selected]

Comment: Does the object have a scale applied?

Comment: No it doesn't. The cube is unedited in any way, besides being moved from its origin.

Comment: Thank you its solved the problem. However what I am still confused about is why does this occur now? I've NEVER had this issue before with so many models before. Why now?